# how to remove some characters from string?

Tags: javascript

After fetching data from api, sometimes it return data as

```
Date: "2020-09-10T13:21:08Z"
```

or sometimes as

```
Date: "2020-05-18T10:11:08Z"
```

Is there any way to remove the characters after T so output can be in yy/mm/dd format like 2020-05-15 only. Date is dyanimic and does not return same all the time. I also want to change the date as 2020/05/16 using "/" instead of "-"

Comment: Example 1 and 2 seems equals to me regarding format. You can use `Date.parse()` anyways

Comment: You can create a substring with `substr`

Comment: See format options https://javascript.info/date

Comment: @felipsmartins it is not same.

Comment: Make a Date instance from the ISO date strings you get, and then use the Date APIs to extract whatever you want.

Comment: That is a date in [standard format](https://xkcd.com/1179/). Parse it and then format it how you want.

Comment: This question is not related to dates really. You have a string, and want part of it. An internet search for substring or something should give you hundreds of clues to choose from. -1 for no effort here.

Comment: @SaralKarki yes actually both dates in your question are ISO standard dates.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this might be to do a simple `split()` on the `T` character, and only taking the first segment:

```js
var dateAndTime = "2020-05-18T10:11:08Z";
var date = dateAndTime.split('T')[0];
console.log(date);
```

---

In a similar text manipulation vein, it'd also be possible to do something similar using RegExp, which might be helpful if you'd like to stick with the pure text manipulation methodology, but the rules by which you're manipulating the date text could become slightly more complex in the future:

```js
var dateAndTime = "2020-05-18T10:11:08Z";
var date = /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/g.exec(dateAndTime)[0];
console.log(date);
```

Comment: This question has been answered many, many times over. Do we need another answer on this question?

Answer (score 0):

If you are always receiving the string in the format shown above you can use the split method and then first element of the array will represent the date part.

```
 "2020-05-18T10:11:08Z".split('T')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also leverage the `Date` API to get the same result, which is sometimes a bit cleaner and easier to extend in the future should your requirements change to more complex date-related manipulation:

```js
var dateAndTime = "2020-05-18T10:11:08Z";
var dateAndTimeObject = new Date(dateAndTime);
var date = dateAndTimeObject.getFullYear() + "-" + (dateAndTimeObject.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + dateAndTimeObject.getDate(); // add 1 to getMonth() result to change from month index to proper numerical month representation
console.log(date);
```